# How to create Apache Virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, wamp, document-root

Im using Windows 7, and there I installed apache server in `c:\wamp\apache\`, PHP is located in `c:\wamp\php\`, and loaded as module.

So lets say I'm building test project and I only have index.php in that project.
Folder of that project will be located in `c:\wamp\apache\htdocs\test\index.php` and I can access that through my browser: `localhost\test`

This all works nice, but I have problem when I include images, css and js files.
lets say I want to include css style, i must use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/images/image.jpg" />
```

and I would like to use this for a href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/images/image.jpg" />
```

So that `/` is root, and from there I can search for files inside my project folder.

What should I do? Should I create virtual server for every project, or there is a way that every folder in my htdocs folder acts as it would on live server, where `/` would translate to document root?

How should I setup Apache server so that every folder in my htdocs folder acts as server for itself?
When I use XAMPP it works like that.

Thanks!

Comment: You should set a document root: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/images/image.jpg" />`

Comment: Yes this would work, but i want to setup my Apache to work like that otu of the box. And since Im using Twig I cant use php inside template. So I really need a way to setup Apache just like XAMPP works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid these kind of headaches, you should have a virtualhost for every project.

You can just put in your httpd.conf (with wamp: left click on wamp > apache > httpd.conf)

```
# To access your old projects under C:\wamp\www
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www
<Directory "C:\wamp\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# each virtualhost should look like that
NameVirtualHost localhost.yourproject.com:80
<VirtualHost localhost.yourproject.com:80>
ServerName localhost.yourproject.com
ServerAlias localhost.yourproject.com
DocumentRoot C:\path\to\yourproject
<Directory "C:\path\to\yourproject">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restard wamp, and include in your hostfile (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.yourproject.com
```